# why does this error keep popping out? Missing } inserted. \int dx = x + C &

Tags: tables, math-mode

This is my code:

```
\begin{center}

    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 

        \hline
        \int dx = x + C & \int \frac{dx}{\cos ^{x}} = tg x + C \\ 
        \int x^{a} dx = \frac{x ^{a + 1}}{a + 1} + C  (a \neq -1) & \int \frac{dx}{\sin ^{2}x} = - ctg x \\ 
        \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

It is displayed how I want it, but this error keeps popping out:

```
Missing } inserted. \int dx = x + C &
```

Comment: Welcome! :) Is, is that really all there is to your code, because you don't seem to be in math mode at all :S

Comment: You need to enter math mode for the math stuff, e.g. `$\int dx = x + C$`, and similar for the other cells.

Comment: thank you, i used $$at the beginning and $$ at the endof the whole table so it didn't work, now i put it inside every column and it works, thank you!

Comment: @KatarinaGrgić Here's a 'trick': if you need to add something (here `$`) before (respectively after) the content of  *each* cell in a column, you can use `>{$}` (respectively `<{$}`) in the columns definition. In your case, you would then have `\begin{tabular}{ |>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}| } `, or even more clever `\begin{tabular}{*{2}{|>{$}c<{$}|}} ` (i.e. `{|>{$}c<{$}|` twice).

Comment: @ebo great advice, but you should mention this requires the `array` package

Comment: note that `$$` should not be used in latex at all, it is a low level tex command but not supported latex syntax.

Answer (score 6):

So the problem is that inside a `tabular` you're always in text mode, so you need to switch to math mode with e.g. `$ .. $`.

That can also be done on a per-column basis, so you don't need the dollar signs in each cell. See second example below. This requires `\usepackage{array}`.

If you use an `array` instead of `tabular` inside math mode, then each cell is also in math mode. See third example below.

But in this case it might look better to just use an `align*` construct, see last example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ctg}{ctg}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d} % thanks egreg
\begin{document}
Math mode in each cell:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
        \hline
        $\int \diff x = x + C$ & $\int \frac{\diff x}{\cos ^{2}x} = \tan x + C $\\ 
        $\int x^{a} \diff x = \frac{x ^{a + 1}}{a + 1} + C  (a \neq -1)$ & $\int \frac{\diff x}{\sin ^{2}x} = - \ctg x $\\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

Two columns all math mode:
\begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{ |*{2}{ >{$} c <{$} | } } 
        \hline
        \int \diff x = x + C & \int \frac{\diff x}{\cos ^{2}x} = \tan x + C \\ 
        \int x^{a} \diff x = \frac{x ^{a + 1}}{a + 1} + C  (a \neq -1) & \int \frac{\diff x}{\sin ^{2}x} = - \ctg x \\ 
        \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\texttt{array} inside \texttt{equation*}:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{ |c|c| } 
        \hline
        \int \diff x = x + C & \int \frac{\diff x}{\cos ^{2}x} = \tan x + C \\ 
        \int x^{a} \diff x = \frac{x ^{a + 1}}{a + 1} + C  (a \neq -1) & \int \frac{\diff x}{\sin ^{2}x} = - \ctg x \\ 
        \hline
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\texttt{align*}:
\begin{align*}
        \int \diff x &= x + C & \int \frac{\diff x}{\cos ^{2}x} &= \tan x + C \\ 
        \int x^{a} \diff x &= \frac{x ^{a + 1}}{a + 1} + C  (a \neq -1) & \int \frac{\diff x}{\sin ^{2}x} &= - \ctg x \\ 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot upvote until you use `\operatorname` (or `\DeclareMathOperator`) where appropriate…

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I didn't really pay attention to the math at all, better now?

Comment: Definitely better! :-)  I realized that I failed to spot the missing thin space in `x^\alpha dx`…

Answer (score 3):

You need to set math content in math mode. However, using `\[` ... `\]` *outside* the `tabular` wouldn't work as `tabular` sets its contents in text mode by default. So, either stick to `tabular` and insert math mode in every cell (or per column with some help from [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array)), or use `\[`...`\]` together with a regular `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array,lipsum}
\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{d}x}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ctg}{ctg}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
  \begin{tabular}{ | >{$\displaystyle}c<{$} | >{$\displaystyle}c<{$} | }
    \hline
    \int \dx = x + C & \int \frac{\dx}{\cos x} = \ctg x + C \\ 
    \int x^{a} \dx = \frac{x ^{a + 1}}{a + 1} + C,\ (a \neq -1) & \int \frac{\dx}{\sin ^{2}x} = - \ctg x \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
  \begin{array}{ | >{\displaystyle}c | >{\displaystyle}c | }
    \hline
    \int \dx = x + C & \int \frac{\dx}{\cos x} = \ctg x + C \\ 
    \int x^{a} \dx = \frac{x ^{a + 1}}{a + 1} + C,\ (a \neq -1) & \int \frac{\dx}{\sin ^{2}x} = - \ctg x \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \hline
  \end{array}
\]

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the mathematics is wrong: it is not `\int \frac{\dx}{\cos x} = \ctg x + C`, but `\int \frac{\dx}{\cos^2 x} = \tan x + C`… :-)  **Edit:** integrating `\frac{dx}{\cos x}` is a little, nice, and classical exercise.